# Qt Qvariantlist conversion into javascript array unsuccessful

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtscript

I'm currently create an apps in Meego using QML and JS on most of the part. and now I stumbled upon a problem.

From javascript I want to call a C++ function to read text file, parse it, and then return an array of the parsing result.
so I create a Q_INVOKABLE function called parse() and call it through javascript

```
function parse() {
    var myArray = new Array();
    myArray = parser.parse("/home/user/MyDocs/angklungtext.txt")
    if(myArray === undefined){
        console.log("null found");
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        console.log(myArray[i][0] + "," + myArray[i][1])
    }
}
```

and here is the parse function in C++

```
QVariantList* QMLParser::parse(QString filename)
{
    qDebug() << "start debugging";

    qDebug() << filename;
    qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();
    QDir dir;
    qDebug()<< dir.absoluteFilePath(filename);

    QFile file(filename);
    if(!file.exists())
    {
        qDebug() << "File: " << file.fileName() << "tidak ditemukan";
        return NULL;
    }

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "Tidak dapat membuka file" << file.fileName() << "untuk ditulis";
        return NULL;
    }

    QTextStream stream(&file);

    QVariantList* myList = new QList<QVariant>;

    while(!stream.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = stream.readLine();
        qDebug() << line.trimmed();
        QStringList lineList = line.split(":");
        myList->append(lineList);
    }

    file.close();

    return myList;
}
```

sadly.
when I try to run it it giving a result like this

```
start debugging 
"/home/user/MyDocs/angklungtext.txt" 
"/home/developer" 
"/home/user/MyDocs/angklungtext.txt" 
"1:1000" 
"4:2000" 
"5:3000" 
"2:4000"
null found
file:///opt/memoryreader/qml/memoryreader/myjs.js:8: TypeError: Result of expression 'myArray' [undefined] is not an object.
```

looks like the C++ parse function successfully parsing the file. it can read it and it can save it into the QVariantList.
but after it return the result into javascript myArray still [undefined].
is there something wrong with the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Just simplify the C++ side like this :

```
QVariant QMLParser::parse(QString filename)
{
    QStringList myList;

    qDebug() << "start debugging";

    qDebug() << filename;
    qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();
    QDir dir;
    qDebug() << dir.absoluteFilePath(filename);

    QFile file(filename);
    if(!file.exists()) {
        qDebug() << "File: " << file.fileName() << "tidak ditemukan";
        return NULL;
    }

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        qDebug() << "Tidak dapat membuka file" << file.fileName() << "untuk ditulis";
        return NULL;
    }

    QTextStream stream(&file);
    while(!stream.atEnd()) {
        QString line = stream.readLine();
        qDebug() << line.trimmed();
        myList << line.trimmed().split(":");
    }

    file.close();

    return QVariant::fromValue(myList);
}
```

And it should work !

Just remember, QML must see a `QVariant`, even if a `QList` is wrapped inside it, and Qt is able to convert most of its base types to `QVariant` using `QVariant::fromValue(T)` so use it extensively.

Oh and BTW a QVariant is reference not pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done this myself, so I'm just thinking out loud.  But I note that you're returning a pointer to a QVariantList...which looks suspect.  (Also: if you `new`, then who would do the `delete`?)

Have you tried returning it by value?

Comment: if i returned it by value, then the return NULL; on some conditional branch there can't be done

Comment: Well, how would you differentiate between returning null and undefined then?  As I say, I haven't really used QtScript, but I thought that rather than returning C++ NULLs and the like from these functions one was supposed to be using things like http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qscriptvalue.html ... depends on what Q_INVOKABLE does but I'd be surprised if it does what you think.

Comment: I'd say, return a QVariant. This can be null if an error is encountered and can also contain the QVariantList (by value) if successful. The JS part should handle the conversion appropriately IIRC.

Comment: Steffen is right, you need to return QVariants by value (or you return QObjects as pointers).